# Do floating points take over integers in a result in Python?

Tags: python

So I have a Python function that sums values from a list:

```
def inc(list):
    if len(list) > 1:
        return list[0] + inc(list[1:])
    elif len(list) == 1:
        return list[0]
    else:
        print("Empty List!")
```

If i apply this function to the list `[1.0, 2, 3.0, 4]` it returns `10.0`. Why does it return a floating point decimal instead of an integer?

Comment: Because the list contains some floating point values. There is an implicit conversion from integer to float when trying to add a float and an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python **coerces** operands to a common type in order to operate on them. In the case of `int` and `float`, both are coerced to `float` and hence that is the type of the result.

Comment: [Relevant section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) in Python documentation: `Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the “narrower” type is widened to that of the other, where plain integer is narrower than long integer is narrower than floating point is narrower than complex.`

Comment: @birryree what do you mean by 'narrower'? I think I've pieced together a good understanding for myself from the comment in OP and this answer so far :)

Comment: @madcrazydrumma - Python has 4 numeric primitive types: `int` (32-bit integer), `long` integer, `float`, and `complex`. In that list, each type is _narrower_ (meaning it can convey/store less information) than the next type. So that means that an `int` is narrower than a `long` is narrower than `float` is narrower than `complex`. When you do math with different types of numbers, the result will be whatever the widest type is (so adding int and a float will yield a float).